# Splitting orders with SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

SQL beginner here.

Since my problem is kinda hard to explain I will try to illustrate it with Excel:

[image]

There are some suppliers, each with a different supplier-number who deliver a certain weight.
Since a truck can only transport exactly 24 tons I'd like to have table with
the orders splitted by the value of 24.
So 30 tons would mean 2 different orders one with 24 tons and one with 6 tons.

Is there any way you know of to solve this problem with a SQL query?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Wouldn't you just have a calculation that does TON_WEIGHT/24, and store that in a ONE column of a table? Why would you need to know one truck needs 24 and other needs 6. instead it would store 1.25, and you would know that this order needs 1 and .25 trucks to take this order. Would already imply 1 truck means full 24 and .25 truck means 6?

Comment: SELECT Tons/30 AS TrucksNeeded                                                               FROM TABLENAME; This gives you the results of it, you can also put this results INTO the table you already have, if you feel like this info is needed in the table, also another reason you might add a column to a table is calculations that are expensive and don't want to do over and over again, but in this case a simple division is fine.

Comment: Also having it as one number like 44.6, this would be read as this order needs 45 trucks. 44 WILL BE FULL, and the next truck will be .6th full. And also, you would be able to use this number lets say 44.6 to calculate a total cost lets say it's $15 per truck, so 44.6 * 15, which is another simple calculation and query

Comment: Why have you tagged it with both Oracle and MySQL? Which database are you using?

Comment: @Omid CompSCI I think I understand what you mean. But for further calculation I'd like to have my data as shown in the picture. I need to exactly know each weight of a truck and assign it to a certain price and in the end add up all calculated prices. Hope I managed to to explain it.

Comment: @Alex Poole: Thanks for the advice. I thought I deleted the "MySQL" tag. I'm working with Oracle!

Comment: @lexcro, I kind of understand based off the picture. However if an order requires multiple trucks wouldn't they all those trucks be going to that order or location, therefore would you just use my way in calculating price. For instance 25/24 =1.04, and you would do 1.04 * $20, means you are charging $20 for 1 truck and $20 for .04 of a truck, or since the .04 is using a WHOLE truck technically an order of 25 tons would require 2 trucks, you could take the ceiling of 1.04 and make it 2, then do 2 * $20, so $40 for this whole order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [recursive subquery factoring](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) (assuming you're on 11gR2 or higher):

```
with r (supplier_number, order_weight, truck_number, truck_weight, remaining_weight) as (
  select supplier_number, order_weight, 1,
    least(order_weight, 24), order_weight - 24
  from t
  union all
  select supplier_number, order_weight, truck_number + 1,
    least(remaining_weight, 24), remaining_weight - 24
  from r
  where remaining_weight > 0
)
select supplier_number, order_weight, truck_number, truck_weight
from r
order by supplier_number, truck_number;

SUPPLIER_NUMBER ORDER_WEIGHT TRUCK_NUMBER TRUCK_WEIGHT
--------------- ------------ ------------ ------------
              1           10            1           10
              2           25            1           24
              2           25            2            1
              3           88            1           24
              3           88            2           24
              3           88            3           24
              3           88            4           16
```

The anchor member gets the original weight, or 24 if it's higher than that, using [the `least()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions087.htm#SQLRF00657) - and that is what is in truck number 1; and also works out what's left (which may be negative here, since it doesn't matter). The recursive member repeats that calculation on the remainder from the previous level, if it is greater than zero.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Assuming my table consists of two rows supplier_numbers and order_weight (as shown in my example) and the table is named "t" this method will work? Unfortunately I'm not able to test it right now but I'll report if it worked tomorrow!

Comment: Yes, I used a CTE called `t` to supply your sample data, and that produced the output I showed; change `t` to your real table name.

Comment: Thanks so much it works! Assuming I'd like to add another row for example the zip code of a supplier how could I do this? Since I'm fairly new to sql I didn't manage to change the code without getting an error.

Comment: @lexcro - another row, or another column? You said 'row' in your first comment but I assumed that actually meant 'column'. If you do mean that, just add the zip code column name in all of the select lists and the CTE column list; `with r (supplier_number, zip, order_weight, ...` etc.

Comment: Whoops sorry! Certainly I meant column :) Everything works perfectly now. Thanks again! if there's anything more I'll let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using recursive factored subquery:

```
with 
     inputs ( supplier_number, order_weight ) as (
       select  1, 10 from dual union all
       select  2, 25 from dual union all
       select  3, 88 from dual
     ),
     r ( supplier_number, shipment_number, order_weight, weight_remaining ) as (
       select  supplier_number, 0, null, order_weight 
         from  inputs
       union all
       select  supplier_number, shipment_number + 1, least(24, weight_remaining),
               greatest(0, weight_remaining - 24)
         from  r
         where weight_remaining != 0
     )
select   supplier_number, shipment_number, order_weight
from     r
where    shipment_number > 0
order by supplier_number, shipment_number
;




SUPPLIER_NUMBER SHIPMENT_NUMBER ORDER_WEIGHT
--------------- --------------- ------------
              1               1           10
              2               1           24
              2               2            1
              3               1           24
              3               2           24
              3               3           24
              3               4           16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a numbers table.  Let me assume that you have one:

```
select t.*, n.n,
       (case when n.n * 24 <= t.tons then 24
             else mod(t.tons, 24)
        end)
from t join
     numbers n
     on (n.n - 1) * 24 < t.tons;
```

Here is one simple way to generate a numbers table, if your table is large enough:

```
with numbers as (
      select rownum as n
      from t
     )
```

Comment: This will not work when t.tons is divisible by 24. Example: t.tons = 24. The join condition will limit `n` to 1, which is correct. But the CASE expression will return 0, not 24. (1*24 is not < 24). (This is easy to fix, change the first < to <=, but expecting better from the top experts on the site...)

Comment: @mathguy . . . I rather miss your comment.  If tons is 24, then only one row should be produced.  Your comment explains why.

Comment: Correct, only one row will be produced, but the weight transported (what the OP calls "order weight" on the right side of the spreadsheet) should be 24. Your formula calculates 0; mod(24, 24) = 0, not 24.